# Reactjs pass function instance to child prop

Tags: reactjs, typescript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, react-hooks

I have three components. `<DroppointMap />` `<Map />` and `<MapMarker />` I've built my components to match the specification of `@googlemaps/react-wrapper` and have installed `@types/google.maps` as well. Used the following docs:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/react-map

I want to be able to use the `fitBounds()` function to make the map zoom in on a given area based on the set of markers I have described as `{lat: 0.0, lng: 0.0}`. I have attempted to make a `useCallback()` hook that returns the function `google.maps.LatLngBounds()` after I have extended the bounds with the function `extend()`

```js
const bounds = useCallback(() => {
  const latLngBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

  droppoints.forEach((droppoint) => {
    latLngBounds.extend(
      new google.maps.LatLng(
        droppoint.coordinates.latitude,
        droppoint.coordinates.longitude
      )
    );
  });

  return latLngBounds;
}, [droppoints]);
```

In my `<Map />` I have my `bounds?: google.maps.LatLngBounds` property specified and I see no complaints from react/ts/eslint or anything else until I run my application that tells me that `google is not defined` in `DroppointMap/bounds` which to me makes little to no sense.

The components are listed below (`<MapMarker />` is irelevant at this point).

#### `droppoint-map.tsx`

```
import { IGoogleCredentials } from '../../context';
import { googleMapsContainer } from './droppoint-map.css';
import { ReactElement, useCallback, useMemo, useState } from 'react';
import { Status, Wrapper } from '@googlemaps/react-wrapper';
import { Map } from './map';
import { MapMarker } from './map-marker';
import { IApiServicepoint } from '../../use-droppoints/types';

export interface IDroppointMapProps {
    googleCredentials: IGoogleCredentials;
    droppoints: IApiServicepoint[];
}

export function DroppointMap({ googleCredentials, droppoints }: IDroppointMapProps) {
    const render = useCallback((status: Status): ReactElement => {
        if (status === Status.LOADING) return <h3>{status} ..</h3>;
        if (status === Status.FAILURE) return <h3>{status} ...</h3>;
        return <></>;
    }, []);

    const [center, setCenter] = useState({ lat: 0, lng: 0 });
    const [zoom, setZoom] = useState(9);

    // omitted for readability
    const mapOptions: google.maps.MapOptions = useMemo();

    const bounds = useCallback(() => {
        const latLngBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

        droppoints.forEach((droppoint) => {
            latLngBounds.extend(
                new google.maps.LatLng(
                    droppoint.coordinates.latitude,
                    droppoint.coordinates.longitude
                )
            );
        });

        return latLngBounds;
    }, [droppoints]);

    return (
        <Wrapper apiKey={googleCredentials.googleMapsApiKey} render={render}>
            <Map
                center={center}
                zoom={zoom}
                className={googleMapsContainer}
                options={mapOptions}
                bounds={bounds()}
            >
                {droppoints.map((droppoint, index) => {
                    return (
                        <MapMarker
                            position={{
                                lat: droppoint.coordinates.latitude,
                                lng: droppoint.coordinates.longitude
                            }}
                            key={index}
                        />
                    );
                })}
            </Map>
        </Wrapper>
    );
}
```

#### `map.tsx`

```js
import {
    Children,
    cloneElement,
    isValidElement,
    PropsWithChildren,
    ReactNode,
    useEffect,
    useRef,
    useState
} from 'react';

export interface IMapProps extends google.maps.MapOptions {
    center: google.maps.LatLngLiteral;
    zoom: number;
    className?: string;
    children?: ReactNode;
    options?: google.maps.MapOptions;
    bounds?: google.maps.LatLngBounds;
}

export function Map({
    center,
    zoom,
    className,
    children,
    options,
    bounds
}: PropsWithChildren<IMapProps>) {
    const ref = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
    const [map, setMap] = useState<google.maps.Map>();

    useEffect(() => {
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-new
        setMap(new window.google.maps.Map(ref.current!, { ...options }));
    }, [options]);

    if (map) {
        map.setCenter(center);
        map.setZoom(zoom);
        if (bounds) {
            map.fitBounds(bounds);
        }
    }

    return (
        <div className={className} ref={ref} id="map">
            {Children.map(children, (child) => {
                if (isValidElement(child)) {
                    return cloneElement(child, { map });
                }
            })}
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just pass `droppoints` to the `Map` component and use them to fit bounds:

```
  const bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  droppoints.forEach((droppoint) => {
    const point = { lat: droppoint.coordinates.latitude, lng: droppoint.coordinates.longitude };
    bounds.extend(point);
  });
  map.fitBounds(bounds);
```

Optionally you could also update the center of the map:

```
  map.setCenter(bounds.getCenter());
```